# C ++ , My for loop doesn't work when I run it on the terminal. Any ideas?

Tags: c++11

When I run it on the terminal it works fine but the loop. The for loop just doesn't do anything at all. I'm learning C++, so I don't know much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
   int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
if (argc == 2) {
    cout << "The first argument is " << argv[0] << endl;
    cout << "The second argument is " << argv[1] << endl;

} else if (argc > 2) {
    cout << "Too many arguments" << endl;
    exit(0);
} else {
    cout << "Only one argument" << endl;
    cout << "The argument is " << argv[0] << endl;
    exit(0);
}

if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0) {
    cout << "Error negative number" << endl;
    exit(0);

}
// this loop does not work, everything else does.

for (int i = 1; i >= atoi(argv[1]); i++){  
    int count = atoi(argv[1]--);
    cout << count << endl;
    int sum = sum + i;
}
cout << "The sum is: " << endl;
return(0);}
```

I think that could be the if statements what are messing around with the loop.

Comment: In for loop, the test condition should be i<= instead of i>= i think.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made mistake in the for loop.
You show use "<=" instead of ">=" in the for loop.

Hope this might helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code is not reaching the `for loop` as you have `exit()` conditions on each and every condition of `if`. Your code only reaches the loop if you are passing 2 arguments in the terminal while you are running your code

Comment: even if I delete the if statements the loop doesn't work at all, no error, just nothing